# Installation of jupyter notebook using pip

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to install jupyter notebook with pip but is giving me this error:Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info
[image]

Reinstalled python and pip,Disabled windows depender

Comment: If you don't wish to sort this out, installing & using [the Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) on your system is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

I installed the Jupiter notebook with Anaconda and install all necessary environments such as **TensorFlow**, **NumPy**, **Matplotip**, and **Ipykernel**, it gives me an error (kernel is dead) so I updated my **NumPy** and **TensorFlow**